# MS CRM - getting the field that caused a form save

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a MS CRM 4 form where when certain fields are changed, I need those fields to be written to an excel sheet.

So, I edited the form field onchange event to call crmform.save() which triggers a plugin to run that writes the field value to a named range (1 cell) of an excel sheet.

However, I don't know which field caused the save.  Is there a way to get that information? (Not all fields on the form need to go to the excel sheet)

If I use this: DynamicEntity target = (DynamicEntity)Context.InputParameters[ParameterName.Target];
I can look at specific fields, but I have no way of knowing which ones changed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, totally changed the way I approached this. I'm using jquery in an iframe to pass all the exact fields (name/value pairs) I want to a method of an ASPX file running in the ISV folder that takes the neccesary action. Thanks for the suggestions all!

Answer (score 1):

It's my experience that only the changed fields will have value (in the DynamicEntity) when you update an entity. So let's say you have an entity with a FirstName and Lastname. If you only change the LastName and save. The LastName will have a value however FirstName with be null (unless you have som javascript code that forces the FirstName to be submitted).

Comment: Right, which doesn't help because there may have been more fields changed in the meantime.  So I am going to come at it another way.  I'm going to build a webpage that runs in a CRM iframe and use jquery selectors to parse the page looking for the fields that I am interested in.  Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin is triggered on the Pre-Event of the Update on your entity, you should be able to compare the `IPluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages` to your `DynamicEntity` that you've fetched from the `Target`.

Or if your plugin is triggered on the Post-Event of the Update, you should be able to compare the `IPluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages` with `IPluginExecutionContext.PostEntityImages`.

Comment: True, but it doesn't tell me which fields are my "certain" fields.  In other words, I only care about certain fields changing.. and only when they change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are already going a different way, but another suggestion is to create a hidden field - "FieldThatChanged."  In your field on-change javascript, set that field to the name of the field that changed, then access that in your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Pre and Post Images as suggested by @Forgotten Semicolon. And in addition set the *Filtering Attributes* so the Plugin is triggered only on the change of the fields you care about.